# Spring method performance show on graph

Tags: java, performance, spring, testing

I would like to ask which tool or program should I use if I would like to create some method (which assume is making some calculations) performance graph, maybe something like below RRD chart :

[image]

which will be presenting the performance of the system and method execution time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use Spring Insight,try this link you will get more info:
http://static.springsource.com/projects/tc-server/2.0/devedition/htmlsingle/devedition.html